# Hashing with SHA1 in python3 does not produce same result

Tags: python-3.x, hash, sha1

I'm trying to write some code preventing the update of modified lists. For this i'm calculating the SHA1 hash of the values, but the hexdigest() of this hash produces different result when i restart my ipython interpreter. Why is this?

```
In [1]: import hashlib

In [2]: hashid = hashlib.sha1()

In [3]: hashid.update(repr(frozenset(sorted(["a","b","c"]))).encode("utf-8"))

In [4]: hashid.hexdigest()
Out[4]: '53ca01b21fd7cb1996634bb45ad74851f73c45d3'
```

When reinitializing the hashid and doing the hash calculation again in the same ipython3 console it works:

```
In [5]: hashid = hashlib.sha1()

In [6]: hashid.update(repr(frozenset(sorted(["a","b","c"]))).encode("utf-8"))

In [7]: hashid.hexdigest()
Out[7]: '53ca01b21fd7cb1996634bb45ad74851f73c45d3'
```

But stopping my console and restarting it it produces different results:

```
In [7]: exit
rvl@laptop ~/ $ ipython3 
In [1]: import hashlib

In [2]: hashid = hashlib.sha1()

In [3]: hashid.update(repr(frozenset(sorted(["a","b","c"]))).encode("utf-8"))

In [4]: hashid.hexdigest()
Out[4]: '6e5813fcb173e35e81d6138eab4d21482885e7eb'
```

Why is this? And how can i produce the same SHA1 hash/hexdigest result when hasing identical sorted lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rely on the ordering of the `repr` of a `set`/`frozenset` object, since the values have no guaranteed order (and in fact, as an anti-denial of service feature, the hash codes of strings will differ between different runs of the same version of Python, causing the `set` ordering to change).

Swap around your `frozenset` and `sorted` calls to get a consistently reproducible representation. Sorted `list`s have guaranteed ordering, while `frozenset` will get you uniqueness guarantees:

```
hashid.update(repr(sorted(frozenset(["a","b","c"]))).encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Ahhh tnx, that makes sense... Could have spent hours looking for this. This clarifies it a lot.

Comment: **Please do not add a comment on an answer to say "Thank you".** If the answer helped you, [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). BTW You were asked 29 questions but accepted only the first. Why?